# Illegal characters in URLs

Tags: permalinks

I have some old permalinks (posts, pages, tags) that contain now-illegal characters in them - and these aren't working anymore.

In previous versions of WP it was allowed to use the non-latin characters, but that changed in newer versions.

Is there any way to clean the database from these permalinks (converting them to allowed format)?

Answer (score 1):

This plugin should allow you to do that http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-utf8-sanitize/